# Can Digital Experience GUIDs be re-used in multiple sites in an org?

Tags: community, salesforcedx, lightning-community, digital-experience

I have an [ExperienceBundle for Experience Builder Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm)
 SFDX deployment working reliably in a CI (Continuous Integration) build.

I'm now working on some scripting to allow multiple instances to be created in a single org by changing various file names and (simple) parts of the content. But I'm stuck getting the often seen pair of error messages:

```
In field: Network - no Network named XYZ found
In field: PicassoSite - no SiteDotCom named XYZ1 found
```

So I am now looking at the content e.g.:

```
{
  "forgotPasswordRouteId" : "0fd7e660-d40d-4c55-96ad-e10999e6cc75",
  "isAvailableToGuests" : false,
  "isFilteredComponentsView" : false,
  "isProgressiveRenderingEnabled" : false,
  "loginAppPageId" : "6b86c3c3-f6b5-4513-a6cb-12f95030d023",
  "mainAppPageId" : "3ba8288a-c74a-4090-aa40-2b24ece42992",
  "preferredDomain" : "none",
  "selfRegistrationRouteId" : "819f2fca-2738-4eb1-b952-0ad35f8f47b3",
  "type" : "site"
}
```

that prompts my question:

```
Can Digital Experience GUIDs be re-used in multiple sites in an org?
```

that amounts to asking if the GUIDs (a) only have to be unique within an individual site in an org or (b) have to be unique within the org?

I assume (a) but would like confirmation.

(GUID = Globally Unique Identifier e.g. `0fd7e660-d40d-4c55-96ad-e10999e6cc75`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my problem thanks to [Diff Folders](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff). When adding substitution tokens instead of this file name:

```
${name}.site-meta.xml
```

I had goofed leaving this file name:

```
${name}.xml
```

With that fixed, I can create multiple Digital Experiences (Sites) using the same GUIDs.

So **yes**, it appears that Digital Experience GUIDs **can** be re-used in multiple sites in an org.

(The deployment process automatically modifies multiple metadata values on deployment, and that may include the GUID values so that at runtime they are unique. But the good news is that we don't have to when deploying multiple times.)

Comment: So the GUID has a uniqueness scope bounded to the digital experience itself. Good to know!

Comment: Yeah @PhilW seems that way - GUIDs are overkill for a few hundred objects with a handful of crosslinks.

Comment: Not so much GUIDs as bundle-unique-IDs...